# Regularization (L1 or L2) for non-linear parameters

Tags: regression, machine-learning, lasso, nonlinear-regression

I was wondering whether it is possible to regularize (L1 or L2) non-linear parameters in a general regression model. Say, I have the following cost function, where  is a 3 vector of fitting parameters:

$=(_1)$ + $_2^{_3}$

and I'm trying to find a sparse solution to the following minimization problem:

$argmin ($  $|| cost - y ||^2 + λΣ_i(|p_i|)$  $)$

In the above cost function, $_1$
and $_3$ are non-linear parameters as opposed to $p_2$.

How should I go about regularizing the model in this case? If all parameters were linear, I could just sum them up together (absolute values or squares), and use the sum as an additional target for optimization, right?

However, I'm not sure if I'm allowed to do so for non-linear parameters.

Has anyone considered this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it no matter where the parameter is. For instance, this is done in neural networks, where the layer weights are highly nonlinearly related to the target value. In general, when the parameters are linearly related to the target, you just have an advantage on parameter scaling so that regularization objective treats each one equally, when feature scaling is performed.

Comment: +1. I do wonder, however, whether nonlinear terms exacerbate the problem of scaling predictors to ensure that penalization affects all the coefficients in reasonably similar ways.

Comment: Nice comment. It can, yes. That is exactly what I tried to imply in the last sentence.

Comment: Thanks. What happens if the cost function contains a parameter which is an inverse, say, 1/p2 instead of p2 in the above example. Decreasing the value of p2 will actually increase the importance of the term that belongs to this parameter. Another example is when a term contains both 1/p2 AND p2 in the same term. Does this mean the regularization is ill-defined for these cost functions?

Comment: The regularization isn't ill-defined, it's just not a good idea unless you're shrinking towards some value other than zero.  There will still be some balancing effect as the fit won't let $1/p2$ go to infinity, but you'll lose some of the benefit of L1 regularization, namely, the potential elimination of terms altogether.

Comment: @David I think jbowman answered very well before me. There will be still an optimization objective and won't be ill-defined.